# Building taxonomies in Latex

Tags: trees, qtree

I need to draw the following structure in Latex:

```
Information systems
    Data management systems
        Database design
            Relational DB
            Graph-based DB
                Hierarchical data models
                Network data models
            Physical data models
            Data model extensions
                Semi-structured data
                Incomplete data
                Temporal data
                Inconsistent data
        Data structures
        Database management system engines
            Database query processing
                Query optimization
                Query operators
                Query planning
            Parallel and distributed DBMSs
                Key-value stores
                MapReduce-based systems
            Triggers and rules
        Query languages
            Relational DBQL
                SQL
            XML
                XPath
                XQuery
    Information systems applications
        Decision support systems
            Expert systems
            Data analytics
        Data mining
            Collaborative filtering
            Association rules
            Clustering
        Digital libraries and archives
```

I have looked through and found that *qtree* package does that. But the thing is that I have even didnt finish 25-30% of the hierarchy and I am getting out of the page. And, on the other side its really confusing with the brackets. Is there any other way to draw hierarchies in LaTex?

```
\Tree[.\fbox{Information Systems} [.\fbox{Data Management Systems} 
               [.\fbox{DB Design} [[.\text{Relational DB} ] [.\text{Graph-based DB} [[.\text{Hierarchical} ] [.\text{Network} ] ] ] ] ]
               [.\fbox{DBMS} [.N ]]
               [.\fbox{Data Structures} [.N ]]
          ]
[.I\1 ]
]
```

Comment: You may try to build the complete hierarchy and use `\resizebox` (or something similar) to fit the graphic in one side. Another possibility: Take a look for the [dirtree](http://ctan.org/pkg/dirtree) package or the [forest](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package.

Comment: Welcome! Could you please make your code compilable? Very relevant: how big is your page and what font and font size are you using? These are affected by your class, packages such as `geometry`, font packages etc. We don't need everything, but we need enough to reproduce the problem you're having which, right now, is like taking pot-shots while blind-folded i.e. unlikely to be to anybody's advantage.

Answer (score 3):

Whether this will fit *your* page, I know not. Fit *mine*, however, it certainly could.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={folder,font=\sffamily,grow'=0, s sep'=0pt},
  [Information systems
    [Data management systems
        [Database design
            [Relational DB]
            [Graph-based DB
                [Hierarchical data models]
                [Network data models]]
            [Physical data models]
            [Data model extensions
                [Semi-structured data]
                [Incomplete data]
                [Temporal data]
                [Inconsistent data]]]
        [Data structures]
        [Database management system engines
            [Database query processing
                [Query optimization]
                [Query operators]
                [Query planning]]
            [Parallel and distributed DBMSs
                [Key-value stores]
                [MapReduce-based systems]]
            [Triggers and rules]]
        [Query languages
            [Relational DBQL
                [SQL]]
            [XML
                [XPath]
                [XQuery]]]
    ]
    [Information systems applications
        [Decision support systems
            [Expert systems]
            [Data analytics]]
        [Data mining
            [Collaborative filtering]
            [Association rules]
            [Clustering]]
        [Digital libraries and archives]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: fit tree to page (arbitrarily chosen, more or less)]